# Elasticsearch: how to index html documents and perform search with "signals"

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, opensearch

I have a set of html documents which I want to index into ES. Is there any html parser integrated in ES, that will extract the content of each html file into various fields (e.g. title, headers, bold texts, actual content..) or do I have to extract these information myself?

Further, I need to perform search over the indexed documents: ES is using bm25; Is it possible to augment the fulltext search with various signals? E.g. if a keyword query has a match with a header or a bold text, then such document should be prioritized over other results.

I am a total beginner to ES - i tried to find answers to my questions in the ES documentation, but not very successfully

Answer (score 3):

HTML strip char filter might be helpful to you - here is the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html)

To add more weight or signal based on formatting - it could be done in multiple ways, For example - you can identify bold or important tokens during index time and add that to an additional field, which will be added to the `should` clause on the query time.